# Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-04e3dd1fd8a1663c3' elasticbean django deployment

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-deployment

i am trying to deploy my django site on aws elasticbean but when i created the envoirment it thows me error

```
021-09-28 07:24:43    INFO    Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-vuemp6euky-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmHigh-10XFBTK55D2M0
2021-09-28 07:24:43    INFO    Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-vuemp6euky-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmLow-Q0TYK7ZDH70U
2021-09-28 07:25:10    ERROR   Instance deployment failed to install application dependencies. The deployment failed.
2021-09-28 07:25:10    ERROR   Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.
2021-09-28 07:25:13    ERROR   [Instance: i-04e3dd1fd8a1663c3] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..
2021-09-28 07:25:13    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2021-09-28 07:26:15    ERROR   Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.

ERROR: ServiceError - Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.
```

then i run eb status i ignored it and move forward after adding cname in allowed host i run the command eb deploy then it thows me a error again

```
2021-09-28 07:30:11    ERROR   Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.
2021-09-28 07:30:12    ERROR   [Instance: i-04e3dd1fd8a1663c3] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..
2021-09-28 07:30:13    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2021-09-28 07:30:13    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-04e3dd1fd8a1663c3'. Aborting the operation.
2021-09-28 07:30:13    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
```

any idea what wrong here i don't understand

Comment: Did you check logs in `/var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log`?

Comment: @Marcin i am new to aws i didn't understand what you are asking for please can you elaborate more that will helpfull thankyou

Comment: You can ssh to the instance, or download full logs using EB console. Then inspect the logs for errors.